# Google App Engine java runtime absolute url

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I need to send out emails containing icon gifs.
It seems that using absolute urls is the best way to achieve this.
In order to do so, I need to get hold of the  the appengine-web-app.xml and its and  so I can build the absolute path.

Is there any straightforward way to get hold of this ?

Answer (score 0):

If you send it in servlet you can get url from request

```
HttpServletRequest.getServerPath();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`ModulesService`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/labs/modules/ModulesService.html):

```
ModulesService ms = ModulesServiceFactory.getModulesService();
String currentModule = ms.getCurrentModule();
String defVersion = ms.getDefaultVersion(currentModule);
String defaultModuleHostname = ms.getModuleHostname(currentModule, defVersion);
```